# Find the 'count of employees' per department & name of those counted employees present in EMP table

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering the already known EMP table, structure like:

> TABLE EMP(EMPNO, ENAME, DEPTNO)

**I want to fetch 'count of employees' department wise  & name of employees present in that department using sql queries.**

*Able to fetch limited data,*

```
select DEPTNO, COUNT(*) as 'Empcount' from EMP group by DEPTNO;
```

But this way I cant get the details of employees.

**I am Expecting like:**

```
DeptNo  Count       Ename
---------------------------------------
10       3          Ford,Allen,King
20       2          Raja,Miller
30       1          John
```

*Thanks in advance for good answers and facts.*

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Ass sample of the expected result. Otherwise we'll close it.

Comment: If you just want one table with employees grouped by department, use an `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` clause.

Comment: DeptNo Count  Ename
---------------------------------------
10   3   Ford,Allen,King
20   2   Raja,Miller
30   1   John

Comment: Try Group_concat. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Thanks P.salmon, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like p.Salmon said in the comments use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
    DEPTNO, COUNT(*) as 'Empcount', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ENAME) Ename  
FROM 
    EMP 
GROUP BY DEPTNO;
```

you can also add a ORDER BY ENAME DESC in thed GROUP_CONCAT if you want to sort the ENAME